# Persist multiple objects with jpa and hibernate, resume on fail

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, iteration, persist

I know that SO has a lot of posts about validating data when persisting objects through jpa/Hibernate. Most of the answers says that a read of data should be performed before the persist so that an exception very rarely is thrown during the actual persistence.

This, as opposed to relying on db constraints, has bad impact on performance. Also, a reason for this extensive read of data before the persist, seems to be important because we really don't know exactly when and how the hibernate exception will appear. But with that reasoning, if an exception arises because of a rare reason we still wont be able to handle it in a good way.

So, my thought was to use a bean (beanA) that iterates over a list of objects and in each iterations it calls another bean(beanB) that has a method called persistOneObject(). persistOneObject() is annotated @requires_new. So on fail only that single transaction is rolled back and we continue with next object in a new transaction.

Should this theoretically work or is it hard to reach this behavior because you're not sure when Hibernate really commits and so on? Is this bad design? I wont supply any code example now since I would like to hear general thoughts on the design rather than specific thoughts about the implementation. Is there any other way to solve it? Or should I go with the read before persist?

Thank you!